# What codes to use in deleting all records on a data table in one click for visual basic studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Hi can anyone tell me what code should i use for visual basic studio 2010 to delete all records on the data table in just one click ? cause if i use RemoveCurrent() it only removes one row at a time. Please help me thanks!

Comment: Do you mean VB.Net? If it is what you mean, you could check `.Reset()`

Comment: yes VB.Net ,i'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional, actually i'm starting to learn visual basic and now i can't seem to find any code for that command till now :( can u help me please i only know RemoveCurrent() which means deleting single row at a time but not all of it in one click.

Comment: What I am unsure about is, the `DataTable` which you mention doesn't even have `RemoveCurrent()` method, are you sure you are referring to `DataTable` class? Or perhaps you actually refer to `DataGridView` component? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Hi thanks i tried it but .Reset() function same as .RemoveCurrent() deleting single row at a time.

Comment: oh sorry i got confuse about that, this is a DataGridView we are tought of .RemoveCurrent() to delete only but not delete all.

Comment: I see, `DataGridView`, not `DataTable`. In that case the answer is there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `DataGridView`, you could use

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
```

To clear all the rows.

Note: not to be mixed with `DataTable`

Comment: Thanks but still same it deleted single row at a time

Comment: Hi i use this code to save my data

Me.Validate()
Me.RecordBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1DataSet)

and to delete, Me.RecordBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

can u check if any of those might be helpful?

Comment: `Rows.Clear()` would have deleted all the items if it is `DataGridView`. As to your next comment, it belongs to a new question, I think.

Comment: I get an error for Rows.Clear it says 'Rows' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'.